# Can we change the tags from sun to Sun and moon to Moon?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

A recent question raised a problem with the current tags.

When referring to the Sun, our star, capitals should be used. This tag could rarely be misused, but that is not the case for the Moon, which orbits Earth and is distinct from a moon which orbits another body.

I think there needs to be some capitalisation of tags.

Comment: Tags are lower case by default. We could fix this by making the tags the-sun and the-moon as they are at Space Exploration.

Comment: Ok, the tag rename is complete.